# Flutter extension isn't defined

Tags: flutter, dart

What's wrong here?

```dart
extension WithNames on ModalRoute {
  static RoutePredicate withNames(List<String> name) {
    return (Route<dynamic> route) {
      return !route.willHandlePopInternally &&
          route is ModalRoute &&
          name.contains(route.settings.name);
    };
  }
}
```

```
Navigator.popUntil(
  context,
  ModalRoute.withNames(['/foo', '/']),
);
```

Why I have `error: The method 'withNames' isn't defined for the type 'ModalRoute'.`
I want to add `withNames` static method to the `ModalRoute` class

Comment: You need to use as `ExtensionName` `.` `MemberName`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use as `ExtensionName.member_name`

For example in this case :

Your `extension` name is `WithNames` and the method name is `withNames` so the call to `extension` method would be

`WithNames.withNames(['/foo', '/']),` instead of `ModalRoute.withNames(['/foo', '/']),`

Reference [dart docs extension methods](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods#implementing-extension-methods)